# Try to design a uniquely solvable masyu

Tags: grid-deduction, puzzle-creation, masyu

**Warning: extreme difficulty**

Does there exist a 6x6 masyu puzzle with one black pearl in each row/column (without any white pearls) which is uniquely solvable? What about for 7x7 grids? In fact, what is the smallest N such that there exists a uniquely solvable NxN grid?

<sub>Hint helpfulness level 0</sub>

> I have no idea what the answer is.

<sub>Hint helpfulness level 1</sub>

> I conjectured the answer was 7 but I have not been able to find a grid that works

<sub>Hint helpfulness level 2</sub>

> You may need a computer for this

<sub>Hint helpfulness level 3</sub>

> You might as well give up if you need this many hints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## There are two solutions for 7x7 grids

(not counting reflections and rotations)

> [image: 7-1]
>  [image]

I found these by brute force.  Each grid can be abstracted as a permutation of 1234567, where each digit represents the column a black pearl is placed on the row correlating to the digit's position.  I used [this javascript page](http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/permutations.html) to generate a list of all 5040 permutations in a space delimited block of text.  I used only the permutations that began with 1-4, because 5-7 would all be reflections of a previous permutation (in retrospect, I could have cut it off at 1-3).

As my coding skill is only slightly past the stone age, it took an embarrassingly long time to hack together code snippets from stack exchange answers to make a batch script that would write a text file for every permutation that would be properly formatted to be evaluated by [Naoyuki Tamura's Masyu solver](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/copris/puzzles/masyu/).  I had to convert the space delimiters in my permutations list (permutations.txt) to newlines, which was easy enough with Notepad++.

Here is the laughable code for the batch script I used to write the puzzle files:

```
echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a countraw=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (permutations.txt) do (
set /a countraw+=1
set count=000!countraw!
set count=!count:~-4!
set tstring=%%a
echo !count!: !tstring!
echo 7 > mgrid!count!.txt
echo 7 >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~0,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~1,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~2,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~3,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~4,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~5,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
set q=!tstring:~6,1!
if !q! EQU 1 echo b - - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 2 echo - b - - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 3 echo - - b - - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 4 echo - - - b - - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 5 echo - - - - b - - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 6 echo - - - - - b - >> mgrid!count!.txt
if !q! EQU 7 echo - - - - - - b >> mgrid!count!.txt
)
```

Obviously, it would have been ideal to structure it as nested *for*'s, but batch is weird about variables in *for* loops and I could never get any variable references to work.  Perhaps someone who knows more about batch scripting can come up with a better solution, or suggest what coding environment I should have used.

In any case, I then put all the text files into a folder with the solver and another batch script, whose code follows:

```
echo off
echo BEGIN REPORT>report.txt
for %%a in (mgrid*.txt) do (
echo %%a
echo %%a >> report.txt
scala -cp copris-masyu-v1-1.jar masyu.Solver -o multi %%a >> report.txt
echo. >>report.txt
)
```

I then searched the report for the string "NumOfSolutions = 1" and rendered all of the results that weren't reflections and rotations of previous results, of which there were the two above.

By modifying the code and testing, I was able to determine that

## There are no solutions for 6x6, 5x5, or 4x4 grids. N=7

EDIT:

I decided to try white pearls as well.  For them, N=4, as there is one solution, not counting its reflection:

> [image]

I tried 5x5, but found there were no grids that would produce a unique solution, which leads me to believe that 4x4 is the only grid size that could produce a unique solution with white pearls.

I'm curious about the upper limit of the grid size for black pearls.  This would certainly require that I figure out some way to pare out all reflections and rotations from the permutation list, which would then leave me with 45360 permutations for a 9x9 grid (as 8x8 has already been proven).  The solver usually finishes smaller grids in about 1 second.  If this is true for 9x9 grids, it would take at least 12 hours to go through all unique 9x9, but I estimate it could easily take double that.

Answer (score 7):

### 8x8 has been solved

> [image: Nazi puzzle]

[Give it a go!](http://pzv.jp/p.html?mashu/8/8/06060006i0000k00020200)

Yes, I know what shape that makes >:)